# Is using sqlite db file with changed extension as registered application file a bad idea?

Tags: .net, windows, sqlite, file-extension

I'm thinking about registering sqlite db file with a custom extension (for example *.myext) as a registered file for my .NET application so that when double clicked it will launch my app just as double clicking a *.doc file launches M$ Word.

I can't think of a reason why this would be a bad idea, can you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `.docx` or `.vsix`, for example, are just renamed `.zip` files, there should not be any issues with having any existing file format under your own extension.

Comment: Thanks, I'm thinking along the same lines but wanted to hear other opinions. BTW, M$ is not a typo but "examle", which you missed, was...

Comment: Yes, the joke seemed to distract from the question, but if you insist on it, let it be.